# MacOS distributedNotification lost on background app Swift

Tags: macos, nsnotifications

I am trying to send a distributed notification to another app, app2 from the app that has focus, app1.  The notification is not acted on until app2 gains focus. To fix it, I activate the other app, then send the notification.  This can't be right.  First, the other app retains focus, second, there is no point to a distributed notification if it is lost unless the other is active.  Note this is a Mac App using AppKit, not an IOS app with UIKit

```
let yes = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "Lip.Balance20")
        
        if yes.count > 0 {
            yes[0].activate( )  // Shift focus to the Balance app  and send notification
            print ("***  App is running!")
            DistributedNotificationCenter.default.post(name: .checkAdded, object: nil,
                        userInfo: ["Application Name" : Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!,
                                    "CheckToAdd":  r,
                                     "Account": a])
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with distributed notifications you should mind an option called [SuspensionBehaviour](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter/suspensionbehavior).

As the `deliverImmediately` doc states:

> The server delivers notifications matching this registration irrespective of whether suspended with an argument of `true` has been called.

You have to either specify to deliver notifications immediately (regardless of the receiving app's suspension status) when you send a notification (this is a slightly different method, note the last parameter):

```swift
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().postNotificationName(
    .checkAdded,
    object: nil,
    userInfo: [...],
    deliverImmediately: true
)
```

Or make sure that you specify it when subscribing to notifications:

```swift
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: ...,
    name: ...,
    object: nil,
    suspensionBehavior: .deliverImmediately
)
```